# Explain Query Tool in AEM 6.1 is showing Oak Indexes being used as blank

Tags: aem, jackrabbit-oak

I am using the Explain Query Tool to understand which tool is being used by AEM to run my query. Though the tool is showing a lot of information, it is not showing the Oak:Index being used. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to know which index is being used  for this query. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If it doesn't show any index, the most simple answer is that it's not going to use any index.

Comment: Check your properties which are used in query and if needed add them to get indexed.

Comment: @Rupesh I have already created the indexes for those properties which are being used (see text as /oak:index/mostrecent) in the first line of the query.
The /oak:index/mostrecent is my index based on the properties being used.